# Extract data from Graph API query in C#

Tags: json, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm querying the Graph API on AAD for group membership information.  From this, I get back a JSON string containing one or more groups to which the user belongs.  I know I can reverse engineer a structure and de-serialize it, but are the Graph API structures available as some sort of contract that I can exploit?

I've found examples of queries against the Graph API that get the raw string data, but I could really use a simple example where someone extracts the raw information (e.g. the group ID or group name) and uses it in a structure.

Comment: Would it be possible to give an example of the JSON you are receiving, and the structure you would like as a result? I think a solid example would help clarify what you are looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a  user class as below

```
public class ActiveDirectoryUser  
    {
        public bool accountEnabled { get; set; }
        public List<SignInName> signInNames { get; set; }
        public string creationType { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string mailNickname { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("passwordProfile", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public PasswordProfile PasswordProfile { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("passwordPolicies", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string PasswordPolicies { get; set; }

        public string city { get; set; }
        public object country { get; set; }
        public object facsimileTelephoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string givenName { get; set; }
        public object mail { get; set; }
        public object mobile { get; set; }
        //public List<object> otherMails { get; set; }
        public string postalCode { get; set; }
        public object preferredLanguage { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public object streetAddress { get; set; }
        public string surname { get; set; }
        public Guid objectId { get; set; }
        public object telephoneNumber { get; set; }


    }

    public class SignInName
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class PasswordProfile
    {
        public string password { get; set; }
        public bool forceChangePasswordNextLogin { get; set; }
    }
```

When getting the response from AD, use newtonsoft.json to  serialize to the corresponding class as below.

```
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;                                           
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ActiveDirectoryUser>(result);
}
```

Trick is JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>(result);